# How to get the corresponding value with previous row

Tags: sql

Suppose we have 4 classes as ClassA, ClassB, ClassC and ClassD. Please follow the below table.

```
Class Name                Grade           Class Name                Grade
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClassA                      O             ClassA                      O 
S1                                        S1                          O
S2                                        S2                          O
ClassB                      A             ClassB                      A
S3                                        S3                          A
S4                                        S4                          A
ClassC                      B             ClassC                      B
S5                                        S5                          B
S6                                        S6                          B
ClassD                      C             ClassD                      C
S7                                        S7                          C
S8                                        S8                          C
```

I have the first table. I want the table to be displayed as the second one using sql query. The description is below.

If a class has a grade, then its students also should have the same grade. e.g. for ClassA, grade is O, so for its students (S1 and S2) also should have grade O. And the same should appear for the rest of the students. Means they should get the grade corresponding to their classes. Student and class are in same column as shown in the above table.

Can anyone answer??How to show the respective grade for the respective students of different classes using sql query?? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Please cooperate` ... what happens if we don't cooperate?  I actually don't know what you are asking for.  A query, table data, something else?

Comment: What are classes and students doing in the same table? Is this just for output or is it your actual data model? If it's the latter than the model is badly broken...

Comment: A table has no inherent order. That means you could also show the records in any other order, e.g. S7, ClassB, S3, S1, ClassA, ... Now how are we (or the DBMS) supposed to know that S1 belongs to ClassA? There is nothing to indicate this. What you are asking cannot be done. You must use human knowledge to fix this. And that should start with a complete redesign: One table for students, one table for classes.

Comment: By the way: Never ask SQL questions without tagging the DBMS. A solution for SQL Server can be quite different from a solution for MySQL for instance.

Comment: I suspect the above table is the desired outcome and the OP is not giving us the entity structure on which this task is based.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is in the same table, what I think is a bad design, you could use the following query to get your desired output. Of course I assume you have a link between the student and the class where he is in.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(Id INT, ClassId INT, Name VARCHAR(25), Grade CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(1,NULL,'Class A','O'),
(2,1,'S1',NULL),
(3,1,'S2',NULL),
(4,NULL,'Class B','A'),
(5,4,'S3',NULL),
(6,4,'S4',NULL),
(7,NULL,'Class C','B'),
(8,7,'S5',NULL),
(9,7,'S6',NULL),
(10,NULL,'Class D','C'),
(11,10,'S7',NULL),
(12,10,'S8',NULL)

SELECT a.Name, a.Grade
FROM (
    SELECT  1 AS cOrder, c.Id, c.Name, c.Grade
    FROM    @table AS c
    WHERE   ClassId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2 AS cOrder, s.Id, s.Name, c.Grade
    FROM    @table AS s
        INNER JOIN @table AS c ON c.Id = s.ClassId
    WHERE s.ClassId IS NOT NULL ) AS a
ORDER BY a.Id, a.cOrder
```

**Result**

```
Name     Grade
Class A  O
S1       O
S2       O
Class B  A
S3       A
S4       A
Class C  B
S5       B
S6       B
Class D  C
S7       C
S8       C
```